# How do I specify which package export to bundle for npm package

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, package.json, rollupjs

Rollup bundles the browser export of a package instead of the node import

I am using Rollup to bundle some typescript code for a node.js application. 
I am importing this [clipboardy npm package](https://github.com/sindresorhus/clipboardy) which defines in its package.json two different exports:

```
"type": "module",
"exports": {
    "node": "./index.js",
    "default": "./browser.js"
}
```

I want to import the `index.js` file, but when I inspect the output of the bundler, I find the code from `browser.js` instead, which doesn't work in a node.js environment.

Here is my Rollup configuration:

```
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'; 
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
export default {
  input: 'src/main.ts',
  output: {
    dir: 'dist',
    format: 'cjs'
  },
  external: ["robotjs", "onnxruntime-node"],
  plugins: [typescript(), nodeResolve({preferBuiltins: true}), json(), commonjs()]
};
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

And finally, I have `"type": "module"` in my package.json

How do I make Rollup use the node export from the clipboardy package?

Comment: I found in the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#conditional-exports) that the "node" import is used when "matches for any Node.js environment", how do I specify this?

Comment: I found a workaround by directly importing the file from the node_modules: `import clipboard from '../../node_modules/clipboardy';`, but I am still curious how would I do it otherwise